# reading github.com/lfch/etcd-io/client/client/go.mod at revision client/v3.5.13: unknown revision client/v3.5.13

Tags: go, etcd

Background: My repository `grpclb` depends on `etcd` and `etcd` depends on `grpc-go`. I do some changes for `grpc-go` and so need to modify the `go.mod` of `etcd` and `grpclb` too. But when I run `go mod tidy` for `grpclb`, the following error message occurs:

```
go: github.com/lfch/etcd-io/client/v3@v3.5.13: reading github.com/lfch/etcd-io/client/client/go.mod at revision client/v3.5.13: unknown revision client/v3.5.13
go: github.com/lfch/etcd-io/client/v3@v3.5.13: reading github.com/lfch/etcd-io/client/client/go.mod at revision client/v3.5.13: unknown revision client/v3.5.13
```

The changes I did for etcd is changed the module name and added a replace rule for grpc module

```
module github.com/lfch/etcd-io/api/v3

go 1.19

require (
    github.com/coreos/go-semver v0.3.0
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.16.0
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.7.2
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20211118181313-81c1377c94b1
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.47.0
)
replace (
    google.golang.org/grpc => github.com/lfch/grpc v1.51.4
)
```

Then I imported the changed `etcd` module in my `grpclb` repo go.mod file.

```
require (
    github.com/lfch/etcd-io/api/v3 v3.5.13
    github.com/lfch/etcd-io/client/v3 v3.5.13
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.48.0
)
```

Comment: Don't you need to have a `client/3.5.13` tag on etcd-io repo of yours? Similar to: https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/releases/tag/client%2Fv3.5.5